# Replace Glyphicons with Font Awesome in CSS using LESS and Grunt

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, gruntjs, font-awesome

Short version: I would like to use a font set to REPLACE Glyphicons *without* also including Glyphicons CSS, and without modifying the source bootstrap.less file.

---

Long version:

Using Bootstrap's own Grunt file and source files as a base, by default a build process will include Glyphicons in the compiled CSS file.

Since I do not plan to use Glyphicons at all, the "lowest hanging fruit" for me is to go ahead and compile this way, but also include the font I will be using (for example, Font Awesome).

However, the more "elegant" way will be to only include the replacement font.

I can modify bootstrap.less, which includes this line:

```
@import "glyphicons.less";
```

such that the Font Awesome less file is used instead. However, the problem with this is that I am using Bootstrap as an "untouchable library" not as a modifiable source file. I want to be able to drop in new versions of Bootstrap at a moment's notice without the need to remember to change this modified line.

Does Grunt have the concept of "replace string A with string B in memory before the compile runs"? Or is there another way to accomplish my goal? Or should I just not worry about it and include both sets of compiled CSS?

Comment: Found this: https://github.com/erickrdch/grunt-string-replace but it won't npm install properly.

Comment: What errors are you receiving when installing that plugin?

Comment: There's a whole stack, but it all begins with Invalid version at Object.module.exports.fixVersionField

Comment: Hmm... not sure what that would be from. I don't get any errors when I do: `npm install grunt-string-replace`.

Comment: Bummer. I'm lucky enough to get this stuff working in the first place. ;) Not in a position to trouble-shoot Node or Grunt. I'll just have to suffer I guess!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `grunt-string-replace`
https://github.com/erickrdch/grunt-string-replace

Comment: Would probably be helpful! I already ended up solving it a while ago; I don't modify Bootstrap's LESS directly, but I "override" the variables with my own LESS file as part of the LESS compile process, which gave me the results I needed. Thanks, though!